# spacing in recycler view item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am facing a problem i cannot resolve. i googled it but couldnt get the solution im looking for.  i have a recycle view as follow:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

this recycle view is showing in the screen as follow
[image]

if you notice, there is no spacing above the text and bottom of the text for each item. most likely due to wrap_content.  i want to add space within the item cell on top and bottom.  something like this image
[image]

if you noticed, i draw red arrows to indicate the extra space and the text in the center of each item list.  how can i add space within the cell(space on top of text and space on bottom of text?  left and right space will be cool too.

when i googled this, i only found code to add spacing between items. but what i am looking for is to add spacing within the cell item itself like the second picture attach.  i would appreciate your help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you are using an adapter for your recycler view and that adapter is responsible to create children. As @cocored said you have to create your own layout. you have to do it in your adapter (usually in onCreateViewHolder).
you can use inflater service to inflate an xml layout for each child.

recyclerview_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

and in your adapter do something like this

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Whatever> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Whatever> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the child layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_child, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each child
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Whatever obj = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(obj.getName());
        ...
    }

    // total number of children
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add a padding to your recycler item. If you're using a default item layout from android I would suggest creating your own layout.

Comment: how do i add the padding?